# How to add axis lines to ellipse

Tags: python, matplotlib, ellipse

I have this simple code that generates an ellipse

```
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})

ellipse = patches.Ellipse((0, 0), 4, 2, angle=45, fill=False)
ax.add_artist(ellipse)

ax.set_xlim(-2.2, 2.2)
ax.set_ylim(-2.2, 2.2)

plt.show()
```

This is the current output:
[ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63UDJ.png)

I need to add axis of ellipse so it would look like this:
[ellipse_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dUcs.png)

Is there a way to do that?
I need a generic way to use in more complex ellipses, thanks.

I tried to search for parameters in patches.Ellipse() to draw those axis lines, but didn't find anything.

Comment: first of all, excellent drawing of the axis in the second image.

Comment: Okay can you help please? :'D

Comment: have posted a relatively quick soluton.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the major and minor axes of the ellipse.

In the code i show, i do the major axis, but you need to work on the angle part (based on the points of the elipse), whereas i just set it to 45 degrees to post a quick answer.

The result of this would give the complete solution.

So, I do something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})
#################################
# you need to figure this bit out
#################################

ellipse = patches.Ellipse((0, 0), 4, 2, angle=45, fill=False)
ax.add_artist(ellipse)

ellipse.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)
ellipse.set_alpha(0.1)
ax.annotate("",
            xy=(ellipse.center[0], ellipse.center[1] - ellipse.height / 2),
            xytext=(ellipse.center[0], ellipse.center[1] + ellipse.height / 2),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<->", color="black"))
ax.annotate("",
            xy=(ellipse.center[0] - ellipse.width / 2, ellipse.center[1]),
            xytext=(ellipse.center[0] + ellipse.width / 2, ellipse.center[1]),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<->", color="black"))
ax.annotate("",
            xy=(ellipse.center[0] - ellipse.width / 2 * np.cos(np.deg2rad(ellipse.angle)), 
                ellipse.center[1] - ellipse.height / 2 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(ellipse.angle))),
            xytext=(ellipse.center[0] + ellipse.width / 2 * np.cos(np.deg2rad(ellipse.angle)), 
                    ellipse.center[1] + ellipse.height / 2 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(ellipse.angle))),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<->", color="black"))

ax.set_xlim(-2.2, 2.2)
ax.set_ylim(-2.2, 2.2)

plt.show()
```

Which leaves you with a plot like this:

[image]

Basically, in summary, the anotate lines let you do the final bits that you require.

EDIT:
I was able to reduce to this:

```py
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})

# patches.Ellipse(center, width, height, angle)
ellipse = patches.Ellipse((0, 0), 4, 2, angle=45, fill=False)
ax.add_artist(ellipse)

ellipse.set_clip_box(ax.bbox)

ax.annotate("",
            xy=(ellipse.center[0] - ellipse.width+2 , 
                ellipse.center[1] - ellipse.height ),
            xytext=(ellipse.center[0] + ellipse.width-1, 
                    ellipse.center[1] + ellipse.height+1),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<->", color="red"))
ax.set_xlim(-2.2, 2.2;)
ax.set_ylim(-2.2, 2.2)


plt.show()
```

which looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something simpler and more readable, something as simple as ellipse.plot_axis() (I know that doesn't exist but was wondering if there's a more straight-forward way)

Comment: you could remove the first 2 `ax.annotate` which were just the verticle and horizontal lines....

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import sin, cos, radians
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'aspect': 'equal'})

##############
ellipse_size = (4,2)
ellipse_rotation = 45
ellipse_position = (0,0)

ellipse = patches.Ellipse(ellipse_position, ellipse_size[0], ellipse_size[1], angle=ellipse_rotation, fill=False)
ax.add_artist(ellipse)

ax.set_xlim(-2.2, 2.2)
ax.set_ylim(-2.2, 2.2)

# math for the start and end axis point positions
ax1_points = [
    (ellipse_position[0]+ellipse_size[0]/2*cos(radians(ellipse_rotation)), 
    ellipse_position[1]+ellipse_size[0]/2*sin(radians(ellipse_rotation))),
    (ellipse_position[0]+ellipse_size[0]/2*cos(radians(ellipse_rotation + 180)), 
    ellipse_position[1]+ellipse_size[0]/2*sin(radians(ellipse_rotation + 180)))
    ]
ax2_points = [
    (ellipse_position[0]+ellipse_size[1]/2*cos(radians(ellipse_rotation+90)), 
    ellipse_position[1]+ellipse_size[1]/2*sin(radians(ellipse_rotation+90))),
    (ellipse_position[0]+ellipse_size[1]/2*cos(radians(ellipse_rotation + 270)), 
    ellipse_position[1]+ellipse_size[1]/2*sin(radians(ellipse_rotation + 270)))]

# ax1 and ax2 contains the start and the end point of the axis ([x,y] format)

# drawing the arrows
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<->", color="red")
ax.annotate("", xy=ax1_points[0], xytext=ax1_points[1], arrowprops=arrowprops)
ax.annotate("", xy=ax2_points[0], xytext=ax2_points[1], arrowprops=arrowprops)
plt.show()
```

produces this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this code, it improves on mine. I modified the end part so that the `ax1_points` and `ax1_points` were not too long (and added a pic).  Nice work.